# SQL Pivot MIN( COUNT (

Tags: sql-server, pivot, aggregators

I have a complicated MS SQL 2005 query with a PIVOT in it...

I have data like this :

```
Data ( clients left join visits ):
ClientID VisitID ServiceID
1        34      5
1        36      2
1        36      5
1        45      2
1        48      2
1        60      2
2        44      1
3        48      2
3        78      3
3        79      2
```

And what I need is this:

```
ID [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
1   0  1   0   0   1
2   1  0   0   0   0
3   0  1   1   0   0
```

The SQL Query I am using is this:

```
select * from 
         (select clients.ClientID, clients.serviceID FROM clients left join visits on visit.cliendid=clients.clientid ) e 
         pivot ( COUNT(serviceID) for serviceID in ([1],[2],...,[54]) ) p
```

But this SQL Query doesn't do what I want, instead it does this:

```
ID [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
1   0  4   0   0   2
2   1  0   0   0   0
3   0  2   1   0   0
```

I need all of the data in the columns to be either 0 or 1, as in, 0 has never used this service, 1 has used this service...
How do I do this?

It would be awesome if I could do pivot ( Math.MIN ( COUNT(serviceID), 0 ) for ... or if I could do ( CASE (COUNT(serviceID) > 0 ) THEN 1 ELSE 0  for ...
but it won't let me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT clients.ClientID, clients.serviceID
        FROM    clients
        ) e 
PIVOT   (
        COUNT(serviceID)
        FOR serviceID in ([1],[2])
        ) p
```